# Deploy SalesForce HTML5 app into device.emulator

Tags: mobile, authentication, html5, jquerymobile

I have created a HTML5 jquery mobile app as this [link](http://www2.developerforce.com/en/mobile/getting-started/html5#jquery).

I can see the sample in browser and its working fine.

They also mentioned that same can be deployed in a mobile device after logging in with your Salesforce credentials.

I could not understand this. Do I just need to login to SalesForce?

Earlier I created my own app, played with it but this seems quite confusing.

Anybody please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't deploy your HTML5 application to a mobile device, what they are referring to here is accessing from the built-in device browser. Its the same process as accessing it from the desktop - login to Salesforce and then navigate to the URL.

If you are on iOS, once you have opened the URL, you can add a shortcut to the homescreen.  This doesn't remove the requirement to login, but will allow you to jump straight to the page once you have entered your credentials.

Another way to access this from the mobile device would be to install Salesforce1 and add your Visualforce page to the mobile navigation menu. If you make it the first element in the menu it will effectively become the home page for the application.

Comment: Cool... Thanks for detailed explanation... It's helpful to understand the scenario properly.

Comment: @Braj Fyi there are also tools like http://phonegap.com/.

Comment: Next step 2 of the linked article from the original post is the best place to start for that, via the Salesforce mobile SDK rather than directly onto phonegap.

Comment: @BobBuzzard You mean, creating hybrid Android/IOS apps?

Comment: Yes - the Salesforce Mobile SDK builds on top of phonegap and stops you having to worry about things like oauth tokens.

Comment: @BobBuzzard That's cool but I was told to develop 1 code-base for both IOS and Android. So, through hybrid Android/IOS way, I can't achieve what I want. Right?

Comment: It depends.  You can have the hybrid app use a remote visualforce page for all of its content, which just means you need a thin wrapper for iOS/Android.  However, it is two separate projects/technologies and you'd need to go through app store review etc.

Comment: So, finally it will be separate code-base for Android and IOS. @BobBuzzard thanks for the detailed explanation and support.